# Unable to start activity due to error in inflating class

Tags: android, exception, layout

I am getting a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` exception rarely. I wonder what could be the root cause.

Contents of `android:background="@drawable/mydrawablebackgroundg"` are

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>    

    <stroke android:width="2dp"
            android:color="@android:color/black"
            />

    <padding android:left="4dp"
             android:top="4dp"
             android:right="4dp"
             android:bottom="4dp"
             /> 

    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="1dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="1dp" 
     android:topLeftRadius="1dp" android:topRightRadius="1dp"/> 
</shape>
```

The layout causing the exception, Line #86 is on

```
<RelativeLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:layout_above="@+id/mylayout" >

     <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/myimageview"
          style="@style/myimageview_style"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
          android:scaleType="fitCenter" android:layout_centerVertical="true"
          android:background="@drawable/mydrawablebackground"
          android:src="@drawable/oohsmiley" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you post that styles.xml file ?

Comment: What does it mean: "I am getting a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError exception rarely"? Is it completely random (including start of application) or is it happen on configuration change after longer run of application (memory leak)?

Comment: Its a random occurrence after using the application for a while.

Comment: so it looks like you have a memory leak. The most common mistake in android is described here: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html

Comment: This did not help. Its generic advice, nothing to do with anything specific on my issue.